# Redis timeout error

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this test code?  The program works fine initially but inevitably, I get Redis timeout errors after a few hours of non use.  Note, I've changed the redis host and password on this post to false information.

Note, I get the same error, whether I use the node-redis or iris-redis driver.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Redis Data Store
var redis = require("iris-redis");
var client = redis.createClient( 6379, "nodejitsudb5555563948.redis.irstack.com");
client.auth("fehehyrj971946ef332e975fbebb4");

client.on("ready", function() {
  client.iris_config(function(er, config) {
      if(er) throw er;
      console.log("Got my server config: %j", config)
//      client.quit()
  });
});


// Define a test route
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  client.incr("seq:test", function(err, reply) {
    console.log("Incremented redis counter: " + reply);
    var body = "Incremented Redis Counter: " + reply;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
    res.end(body);
  });
});

app.listen(8001);
console.log('Listening on port 8001');
```

Comment: whats the output of CONFIG GET timeout on your redis server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `timeout` not set to `0` on your `redis-server`. If your application is supposed to be idle for a long period of time, you should have set your `timeout` to `0`. You can check your config file or use the following via `redis-cli`:

```
CONFIG GET timeout
```

If this is already on your production servers and you aren't allowed to put it down for a while, you can do the following to set the redis `timeout` dynamically using `redis-cli`:

```
CONFIG SET timeout 0
```

Then don't forget to set the following line on your redis config file:

```
timeout 0
```